# Refresh the TTL of APC without loading the data

Tags: php, apc, ttl

So, like the title says, is it possible (and how) to refresh the TTL of a specific APC cache without fetching the data, then re-storing the data?

Comment: How can you be sure it's still actual if you don't fetch it?

Comment: @zerkms `apc_exists` will let me know if it is still there

Comment: but it won't let you know if the contents is still actual. If you want something that lives long and you don't care of its contents - just set its ttl to `0`

Comment: @zerkms your right, that is exactly how it works. When I was doing some tests before, when the ttl was set to 0, it was clearing instantly, so I had dismissed it. But thanks for clearing that up